# PHPで変数の整理にお知恵を貸してください

Tags: php

```
$a1 $a2 $a3 
$b1 $b2 $b3 
$c1 $c2 $c3
$d1 $d2 $d3
```

このような変数があったとき、変数[1-3]全てにおいてnullだった場合に上に詰めたいです。
フォームからとるので、どこがnullになるかわかりません。

アナログに

```
if($a1==""&&$a2==""&&$a3==""){
$a1=$b1
}
```

などとしようとしましたがD列について書こうとするとかなり大変で。
すっきりと詰めることができればと思い質問します。

Comment: 「上に詰める」という使い方をするのであれば、個々に変数を定義するのではなく、２次元配列を使えば良いのではないでしょうか。
配列なら、上に詰めるコードを書くのも簡単で済むと思います。

Comment: 他の方も書かれていますが、データの"集合"は配列にした方が扱いやすいことが多いです。ただ現状の情報だけではそれが最善かはわかりませんから、フォームの入力値をどのようにそれらの変数に設定していて、詰めた後にどう使いたいのか、といったことがわかるように、現在のコードを載せていただけると具体的な提案がしやすいかと思います。